# Memory problem - CPU high usage in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, error

I have a problem with a site, in which I try to find out what is wrong. The website is kiteclub.gr. I think that following two scripts are corresponding for the high memory usage from ie and cpu:

URI: [removed]
URI: http://cdn.wibiya.com/Toolbars/dir_0024/Toolbar_24280/toolbar_24280_4c90bb56d2aa3.js

If you let the website open and you do something else, after some minutes new tabs of the site opens and new windows of internet explorer!

do you get error on the same scripts in IE? If yes can you copy-paste the errors? Also do you agree that this make the site to use so much memory and cpu?? Or you think there is another problem? Any advice to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't mean to be a jerk by any means, but @bdadam is right, you need to rebuild the site at some point in the future. Having peeked at the source code, it's just bad...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's too hard to debug those JS-files, costs much more time, as you can expect somebody here to do.
I suggest, that you remove all scripts and flash from your page, and put them back one after one, testing each one looking for the phenomenon, when it comes back again. That way you can be sure, which script or flash object is buggy.

But even if you find the buggy script, your site should be havily redesigned. You have way too much inline styles and scripts and some of the scripts look very old-fashioned, not in their own namespace, polluting the global namespace. And so on. I'm sure there are better and newer alternatives for your demands. (e.g. Look for jQuery plugins.)

I wish you good luck with your site. Cheers,

Adam